# iTunes share Library not Loading Correctly

Tags: ipad, home-sharing

I turned on home sharing on my iMac & I want accessing my library from my iPad. The setup went smoothly and I was able to access my Library from my iPad but some of the content isn't showing up correctly. To be more specific some TV shows are listed more than once and some others are not shown at all. How do I fix this.

[image: Yeah I like anime XP]

PS (All my devices are running the latest software)

Comment: Can you add some screenshots?

Comment: Even the titles are all wrong

Comment: My first guess would be wrong tagging. Did you buy them in the iTunes store or import them from some other sources?

Comment: They were all imported into iTunes manually...

Comment: When I import directly through iTunes they show up fine >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem & set the artist of all shows to the name of the TV show & set all episode IDs in the form of S#E# (season number & episode number)

PS. when setting the episode ID of the first 9 episode write the as "05" not just "5" else they will not be sorted correctly.

Comment: Removing the files form iTunes (without moving the files to trash) & then reimport them really helps too

Answer (score 0):

iTunes combines TV Shows based on the available metadata (Title, Series etc.). I've included a sample based on the "The Office Season 8" Sneak Peak below to give you an idea about sensible values.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: They are combined correctly in iTunes on my mac it's just when I access them through home sharing in my iPad that I have problems.