# How can I get rid of duplicate TV shows in my iPad’s list of Home Sharing shows on my Mac?

Tags: itunes, ipad, ios, home-sharing

I’ve got a Mac mini running as a media server-type thingy. It’s running Mac OS X 10.6.8 and iTunes 10.5. I access TV shows on it via my iPad (running iOS 5.0) using Home Sharing.

(The Mac mini is plugged into an Airport Extreme via ethernet, and the iPad accesses it over wifi.)

A little while ago, the list of shared TV shows on my iPad seemed to get a bit screwed up. Several seasons of one show were listed several times, and seasons of shows sorted after that show don’t appear.

I’ve disabled and enabled Home Sharing on the Mac and the iPad, restarted iTunes and the Mac, killed the Video app on the iPad, and restarted the iPad. Still, the list is screwed up.

However, the list of shows is fine on the Mac mini, and on my primary Mac when accessing the TV shows via iTunes. So I’m assuming it’s an iPad problem.

Has anyone else come across, and found a fix for, this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Home Sharing videos on iOS has had some issues for a while now - TV shows out of order and in some cases duplicates. To my knowledge there isn't a proper fix, but some people have suggested that signing out of Home Sharing then back in again on the iPad (i.e. removing your username and password) can fix it some of the time.

Comment: Ah yes: I found that and gave it a go, but sadly no dice — the iPad did seem to reload the shared library from the Mac (as it was slow to come up), but it had the same problem as previously.

Comment: That's too bad. It didn't solve my sorting issue either. There's more info in this [Apple.com Discussions thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3375480?start=0&tstart=0), maybe you'll find something that helps. Seems like we've got to hope for a fix in a future iOS version however.

Comment: Indeed, fingers crossed for 5.0.1. This question suggests that removing and re-adding the video files themselves in iTunes might help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29138/itunes-share-library-not-loading-correctly. Once I have time to try it I’ll report back whether it works.

Comment: I tried that, didn't solve my sort issues, but I don't have any issues with duplicates, so can't say whether it could help or not. I did file a bug with Apple on the sorting issue however.

Comment: Ah — yes, I don’t actually have any sorting issues. Did you try setting Artist and Album Artist to the name of the show, Album to the name of the show plus its season, and the episode IDs as suggested in that answer?

Comment: In a limited test, setting the *Episode ID* tag seemed to work, but it's a bit of a kludge, as it should sort by *Episode Number*, and my auto-tagging scripts use Episode ID for the production number of the show, so it's a bit of a pain to change around. The reality is, I rarely use Home Sharing for videos, so it's not a big issue currently, I would like it if they fixed it though.

Comment: Ah sure. iTunes metadata does seem like a bit of a mess, which after 10 years is understandable I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this issue on my iPad. Shared TV Shows had many repeats, one couldn't navigate. This all came from the items I'd ripped from DVDs that I'd purchased on put into iTunes.

Setting the Artist and Album Artist fields to something appropriate for the show fixes it. (select the similar shows in iTunes and use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to edit them all at once)

Done!